# How do I build a search engine in PHP to search live content of multiple sites?

Tags: php, curl, web-scraping, search-engine

I am a relatively novice programmer with a good understanding of PHP but more of the case of read, understand and copy the bits I need rather than develop from scratch.

I have a list of over 1000 URLs I would like to search. I would like to search those pages for content on demand and return only results containing the text query I provide. I have looked at Google Custom Search Engine as an easy option and this works well but limits the amount of pages I can add.

I've looked into cURL but doesn't seem to offer what I'm looking for unless I'm missing something?

Or are there other options like Google CSE that are free and easy to use?

Answer (score 0):

You can write crawler for needed pages and use Sphinx engine(http://sphinxsearch.com/) for search in pages. For my opinion, should write a crawler with HTTP extension is better than pure cURL lib.

Comment: I'll take a look at Sphinx, out of interest do you know of any tutorial sites for writing a crawler?

Comment: You can start here [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_crawler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_crawler) and also look at this [http://astellar.com/php-crawler/](http://astellar.com/php-crawler/) for more examples

Comment: One more lib for scraping and web crawling - [Goutte](https://github.com/fabpot/Goutte)